# Unable to install a module in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder

I have a following problem. I am using Spyder IDE (but no Anaconda). I want to install `statsmodels.api`. See my steps (I write them in IPython console):

1)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-085740203b77>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as sm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

2. 

```
pip install statsmodels
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then I restart kernel using `ctrl` + `.`
3)

```
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Restarting kernel...
```

But know, when I try step 1) again I see no progress. In other words, module is not installed.

4)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-085740203b77>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.api as sm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

Where is the problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!pip` instead of `pip` in IPython console.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this anywhere!